# DD-WRT AP with Client mode bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, bridging

I currently have a TP-LINK WR1043ND v1 running DD-WRT.
Earlier I ran this router as an Access Point. Sincee I moved the router to an room where I don't have an Ethernet connection, I decided to use the Client Mode from DD-WRT, which resulted in problems. My router works normally when I use it with a cable, but it was invisible from the wireless network. I read that you have to create virtual interfaces to use the wifi network. I thought: okay, this should fix my problem. But when I did this I couldn't see my computer (connected using ethernet cable) from my laptop (connected to the wifi). Does anyone have a solution for this and the reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

> To have computers connected to both routers (main and secondary) and
>   co-exist in the same subnet, set up DD-WRT as a Client Bridge,
>   Repeater Bridge or use WDS. Further explanation of bridging modes is
>   in the Glossary.

[Source](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless)

Comment: Client bridge isn't an option becuase I need a different subnet, Repeater Bridge isn't supported by my router and WDS don't work

Comment: Well... maybe because Repeater Bridge is not supported, it won't work

Comment: @ApocalypsjeNL: Well if you need a different subnet then you need to manually configure static routing to that subnet on your main router and configure it as a bona-fide router instead of a NAT gateway.